# Internal differentiation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Below is a parametrized equation for  Initial Value Problem (IVP) for Ordinary Differential Equations:

$y'(t; p) = f(t, y(t;p), p)$

$y(t_0) = y_0(p)$

where p is the model parameter. The first order solution (for the sensitivity) with respect to the model parameter $p$ is defined as:

$S_i(t;p) = { \frac{\partial}{\partial p} } y(t;p)$.

I need help to show the proof of $S_i'$ which gives a result of:

$S_i' = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}S_i + \frac{\partial f}{\partial p}$ and $S_i(t_0) = \frac{\partial y_0(p)}{\partial p}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided $S_i, f, y $ are suitable smooth enough to swap the order of differentiation:
$S_i' = \frac{d}{dt}{ \frac{\partial}{\partial p} } y(t;p)=\\
{ \frac{\partial}{\partial p} } \frac{d}{dt}y(t;p)=\\
{ \frac{\partial}{\partial p} }f(t, y(t;p), p)= \qquad\mbox{(usage of the chain rule)}\\
{ \frac{\partial}{\partial y} }f(t, y(t;p), p) { \frac{\partial}{\partial p} } y(t;p) + { \frac{\partial}{\partial p} }f(t, y(t;p), p)=\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}S_i + \frac{\partial f}{\partial p}$

Comment: Thanks a lott!!